# create shape xml file in drawable folder in android studio

Tags: android, drawable, shapes

I am using Android studio 1.2.2 and need to know how to create a new shape file in drawable folder. I have already done the same in Eclipse but unable to do so in the android studio 1.2.2

Answer (score 44):

follow these steps

1. create a drawable folder in res directory.(if not present)
2. right click on *drawable* folder> **New > Drawable resource file**
3. Give your file a name and change the **root element** to **shape**.
   (its selector by default)

now you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you.. It is so much easier in Eclipse ADT where the root tag is displayed in a list for selection

Comment: Yes.But it's autocomplete in android studio so have to type only sh and it will appear :) .Do accept the answer if it helps.

Answer (score 30):

I was confused by the post from Anirudh when he said to change the root element to shape. But here is full demo.

Basically, the shape element is not provided by drawable resource file list by default. So just create one and then change the root xml element to shape, manually.

[image]

Comment: What content does this accept?  It's not liking a `<path` element

Answer (score -2):

1. Right Click On *drawable* folder
2. Select *New* -> *XML* -> *Layout File*
3. Type Root Element *shape*

Comment: In android studio, this is generating a layout xml file in layout folder. even can't move to drawable folder. So this is not an answer for this question.

Comment: think you meant New -> Drawable Resource File

Comment: this is for creating layout file, not shape file.