# How to make a circular Button?

Tags: android, xml, shapes

I'm a new to Android Development. While working on Android Studio 2.2, I tried to create a **circular Button**. As read from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468454/create-shape-xml-file-in-drawable-folder-in-android-studio), I tried to create a new **Drawable Resource File**. But I was unable to change **Root Element** to **Shape**. There was no such options. Could anyone help?

Comment: do bit research before posting here

Comment: Why? Is it against rules?

Comment: Yes, here are the rules: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions.
Floating Action Button: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html

else:
You create a oval shape in xml.
and put that shape as background on button and make sure button have equal layout_height and layout_width.

Example:
oval_shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>

</shape>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

  <Button
      android:layout_width="60dp"
      android:layout_height="60dp"
      android:background="@drawable/oval_shape"/>



</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

No option is needed here. Just use `<shape>`.
Check this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/btn_radius" />
</shape>
```

Comment: As you said, I created the file. But it contained.. ` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</selector> `

Comment: @JosephVM just replace everything with what you want. Doesn't have to be a `selector`.

Comment: OK.. That worked. Thanks @Hamed. Meanwhile, can you clarify what is a **Root Element**? Also what is a **Selector**? I like to learn more about these.

Comment: The root element is the first element after the `<?xml...` tag. The `selector` is used to define different shapes for different states of the button like when it's pressed or when it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Use xml drawable like this:

Save the following contents as round_button.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#fa09ad"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#c20586"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

And set it as background of Button in xml like this:

```
<Button
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="@drawable/round_button"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:text="hello"
android:textColor="#fff" />
```

Comment: I changed `android:shape="oval"` to `android:shape="ring"`. But nothing in preview??

Comment: why are you changing it to ring?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the [FloatingActionButton](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button)
It is available in the support-library.
The [documation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) of the class.